# Handling zooms when routing in single page appications

Tags: angular

I have an angular app and when the user logs in the screen sooms in on the iphone when they type in their credentials.

Then they login and it takes them to another page via the router, but because the page does not refresh the zoom does not reset on the iphone.

What's the best practice for handling iphone zooms with angular routing?